# Visual Studio Setup Project - Close app before installing

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, windows-installer, visual-studio-2022, setup-project

I have developed a simple windows form based application which is used to schedule work for a day and send it out to operatives.

This is in its early stages and we're currently applying necessary changes/updates as we learn new things about how they work and what the data shows.

The application is currently deployed via Microsoft InTune and sent to the devices (of which there are around 30). This process works fine for first-time install, however when upgrading to new versions we find problems with the application being "in use" and operatives forgetting to close at the end of the shift.

I have created a visual studio setup project to manage the install by producing an MSI and have the following settings turned on:

[image: setup project settings]

I need the application installer to close the app down silently (which is currently limited to 1 instance) then proceed to install. I have so far been unable to find any working solution.

I thought about using custom actions but it always continued to give the message that the application was open, even though the custom action was set to close it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could use [PSADT](https://discourse.psappdeploytoolkit.com/t/how-to-show-closing-defer-prompt-to-user/2560) to deploy the application and prompt the user to close (or automatically close) the application and then proceed to the installation.